# How to UNION parts of different sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 4 parts, each part is made out of 2 select statement. I need the 1st 2 part to be UNION'd with the 2nd part. Each part contains its own ORDER BY. I need the results to appear 1st part first and followed by the 2nd part. Only each part is sorted but not the overall result set.

```
(select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from tableA where col1 = 'x'
UNION ALL
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from tableB where col1 = 'x'
ORDER BY Col3) --1st part ends here
--now I need to UNION the 2nd part
UNION ALL
(select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from tableA where col1 <> 'x'
UNION ALL
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from tableB where col1 <> 'x'
ORDER BY Col3) --2nd part ends here
```

I tried wrapping each select in the SELECT * FROM (... but I'm having issues with ORDER BY. Just can't seem to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a column for this purpose:

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5, ord = 1 from tableA where col1 = 'x'
UNION ALL
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5, ord = 1 from tableB where col1 = 'x'
UNION ALL
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5, ord = 2 from tableA where col1 <> 'x'
UNION ALL
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5, ord = 2 from tableB where col1 <> 'x'
ORDER BY ord, Col3
```

Comment: Simple and clever. Thanks bud.

Answer (score -1):

The ORDER BY applies over the whole result set, after the UNION. See Example C: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

You can't have the ORDER BY in the queries within the UNION.